# Converting Ruby to PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress

I'm not a PHP guy and I need to convert this code from Ruby to PHP which I'll insert into a WordPress website:

```
#controller

def action1
  @value1 =
    if @current_user
      @current_user.value1
    else
      if cookies[:value1].blank?
        value1 = SecureRandom.hex(6)
        cookies[:value1] = {
          :value => value1,
          :expires => 5.years.from_now.utc
        }

        value1
      else
        cookies[:value1]
      end
    end
end

#view
<script>
  someMethod({'key1': <%= @value1 %> })
</script>
```

where `@current_user` is an instance of a **model** User. Here's my attemps:

```
# 123.php (view)
<?php
  $user = get_current_user();
  if ($user) {
    $value1 = $user.value1();
  } else {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["value1"])) {
      $retVal = "????"; // how to generate 12 random digitst the way SecureRandom.hex(6) does?
      setcookie("value1", $retVal, time() + (86400 * 30) * 365 * 5, "/");
      $value1 = $retVal;
    } else {
      $value1 = $_COOKIE["value1"];
    }
  }
?>

<script>
  someMethod({'key1': <?php echo $value1 ?> })
</script>
```

I'm not sure `get_current_user()` is what I'm looking for, though.

Other mistakes?

Comment: are you try **global $current_user** in wordpress **get_currentuserinfo()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Ruby guy, but at least the following should be valid PHP.

```
<?php
  $user = get_current_user();
  if ($user) {
    $value1 = $user->value1(); ///// need to use -> not .
  } else {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["value1"])) {
      $retVal = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(6); ////// 
      setcookie("value1", $retVal, time() + (86400 * 30) * 365 * 5, "/");
      $value1 = $retVal;
    } else {
      $value1 = $_COOKIE["value1"];
    }
  }
?>

<script>
  someMethod({'key1': <?php echo $value1 ?> })
</script>
```

See [manual for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php).

Comment: does `get_current_user()` return a model of a user from a table, in particular, is "value1" a column in that table? In my example, "value1" is a column in the table Users.

Comment: PHP doesn't really have built-in models. So, it will depend on writing `get_current_user()` to return an object that has a value1 member. I assumed you had that. I don't know the WordPress environment so I don't know if there is such a function. Sorry.